# Screen record concurrent browsers during Selenium tests

Tags: browser, selenium, screen-scraping

I want to videorecord Selenium test cases in IE, Firefox, Safari, ...

When using Selenium Grid, a node can be processing multiple tests at the same time. I need to record a video of each browser currently executing the testcase.

I was thinking to maybe make a wrapper script where I pass the browsername and other args, which would then invoke the browser, get the window handle and record the session in C#.

Is this a good idea? Are there other solutions already available?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have a look [Test case recording](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/blog/2010/castro-selenium-video.html)